# Iterating & Rendering SVG in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I've been doing iteration map with react for quite long now with many success. The only thing I haven't encounter is rendering SVG with iteration.

Start with react component setting up iteration mp and importing array of data from `./data.js`.

**Cards.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import data from './data';

const icons = data.map(icon => (
  <>
   <div><span>{icon.svg}</span> {icon.type}</div>
  </>
));

const Cards = () => (<>{ icons }</>);

export default Cards;
```

Array of data...

**data.js**

```
export default[
 {
   svg: './icons/menu.svg',
   type: Menu
 },
{
   svg: './icons/home.svg',
   type: Home
 },
 {
   svg: './icons/clock.svg',
   type: History
 }
]
```

Problem is, its unable to render .svg following directory but end up rending string `./icons/xxx.svg` instead.

I've tried another method..

```
svg: require('./icons/clock.svg'),
```

... still getting same result. I'm Running out of idea. Any suggestions? I understand `require('')` worked with JSX img tag... But I wanetd .svg files only, is there a way to import svg files into data array?

Comment: Have you tried this <div><span>{require(icon.svg)}</span> {icon.type}</div>

Answer (score 4):

Try setting it up like so:

```
import menu from './icons/menu.svg';
import home from './icons/home.svg';
import clock from './icons/clock.svg';

export default[
 {
   svg: menu,
   type: 'Menu'
 },
{
   svg: home,
   type: 'Home'
 },
 {
   svg: clock,
   type: 'History'
 }
]
```

And implement it like this:

```
<div>
  <span>
    <img src={icon.svg} />
  </span> 
  {icon.type}
</div>
```

Comment: @Ted suppose if u have 100 svg files then ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys taking time to help... Those method do work, gave me idea and I am keeping note of it. But it was not exactly what I was looking for since it'd have to use `<img>` tags which will not allow me to adjust size, color or etc. I want to avoid going back and forth between code editor and illustration programs. Fortunately, I found alternative solution, it may be tedious but it works. Here what I did...

Start with creating React PropTypes component..

**Icon.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const config = {
  svg: {
    display: 'flex-inline',
    margin: '0 auto'
  }
};

const Icons = props => (
  <svg
    style={config.svg}
    width={`${props.size}`}
    height={`${props.size}`}
    viewBox={`0 0 512 512`}
    className={props.className}
  >
    <path d={props.icon} />
  </svg>
);

Icons.propTypes = {
  icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  color: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

Icons.defaultProps = {
  size: 32
};
```

Create another file and include array of SVG path with defined name *eg. menu, home, clock*

**icons.js**

```
export const SVGicon = {
  menu: /*Insert your SVG path here starting with 'M...*/, 

  home: /*Insert your SVG  path here starting with 'M...*/,

  clock: /*Insert your SVG path here starting with 'M...*/,

}
```

Back to data.js and modify a little (Thank you Ted!)

**data.js**

```
import { SVGicon } from './icons'

export default[
  {
    svg: SVGicon.menu,
    type: 'Henu'
  },
  {
    svg: SVGicon.home,
    type: 'Home'
  },
  {
    svg: SVGicon.clock,
    type: 'History'
  }
]
```

Back to react components and modify a little...

**Cards.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import data from './data';
import Icon from './Icon'; /* PropType Component */

const icons = data.map(icon => (
 <React.Fragment>
  <Icons icon={icon.svg} className="svg-icon" size={12} />
 </React.Fragment>
));

const Cards = () => (<React.Fragment>{ icons }</React.Fragment>);

export default Cards;
```

and the css following `className="svg-icon"` to adjust color, effect and etc

**main.scss**

```
.svg-icon{
  fill: rgba(blue, .5);
  transition: fill .3s ease-out;
  &:hover{
    fill: rgba(red, 1);
 }
```

This should show array of different SVG icons, with ability to control color, size and etc... Hope this help

Comment: i am trying to load some 50 svgs from the public folder and can u tell me what is the best approach to follow? @sirrius

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am not sure I understand what you mean about "SVG from the public folder"?

Comment: say i have 50 svg files in folder like a.svg,2.svg,3.svg..... and i want to display these svg in table

Comment: please check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260773/unable-to-display-svgs-from-local-folder-using-react-js/56261233#56261233

Comment: I understand, you want to implement 50 .svg from public folder at without set it up individually? If so, look up to ted's answer above. Create a folder called icons or whatever you like to name it. Place all 50 .svg inside folder... Import all svgs and set up arrays. This is probably most convenient and best approach.

Comment: @sirrus Thanks for you answer. What if Svg icon have not the only one path, how to store this in data?

Comment: @sirrus But what if the svgs have different viewbox. How can i iterate through such svgs

Answer (score 0):

Keep your data as it is and use require to render it

```
<div>
  <span>
    {require(icon.svg)}
  </span> 
  {icon.type}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this as a comment to @sirrius, but not enough reputations :)

I followed the solution provided but my icons were not visible. This is because the view port is still taking static values, instead of the dynamic size values for width and height.

So instead of:

```
const Icons = props => (
  <svg
    style={config.svg}
    width={`${props.size}`}
    height={`${props.size}`}
    viewBox={`0 0 512 512`}
    className={props.className}
  >
    <path d={props.icon} />
  </svg>
);
```

which would have the icons taking a viewBox height and width of 512 irrespective of the size prop (imagine having an svg of size 32 inside a 512 viewBox, it could appear to be out of sight cause of the dimensions are not proportional).

You should have:

```
const Icons = props => (
  <svg
    style={config.svg}
    width={`${props.size}`}
    height={`${props.size}`}
    viewBox={`0 0 ${props.size} ${props.size}`}
    className={props.className}
  >
    <path d={props.icon} />
  </svg>
);
```

This adjusts the viewBox with respect to the size provided.