# unable to display svg's from local folder using React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

what i need : I am trying to display svg from external folder and that folder contains some 50 files and

```
public folder
  |-images
        -| 50 svgs
```

in app.js

i am trying to display the image

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import svgs from "../public/svgfolder/0.svg"
class App extends React.Component{

   render(){
     return(
       <div>
         <img src={svgs} alt="test"></img>
       </div>
     )
   }
}

export default App;
```

i am getting below error

> Module not found: You attempted to import ../public/svgfolder/0.svg
>   which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports
>   outside of src/ are not supported.

here i need  3 things

1. How can we display 50 svgs dynamically in react ?
2. some people are suggesting to make change in the web pack so is it right approach i mean will it work in production also ?
3. do we have to use public folder or any other folder ?
4. React support svg's  ?

Note : if i call svg through url `<img src={"https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg"}/>`,

it is working and if the same using local file it is not

and if u put the svg single file **src** folder then a single file can be able to display

Comment: Have you looked into SVG middleware? Have you looked into whether or not webpack can compile SVGs without a loader? Have you looked into inline SVG as React Components?

Comment: Just so you know, if you put an SVG in an IMG tag it will not behave like an SVG. It will behave like in image. See my answer below for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have the same scenario where i tried this approach and it worked u can try

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

var images = [];

class App extends React.Component {

     importAll(r) {
      return r.keys().map(r);
    }


  componentWillMount() {
    images = this.importAll(require.context('../public/public/svgfolder/', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
         {images.map((image, index) => <div> <p>{index + 1}</p> <img  key={index} src={image} alt="info"></img> </div>  )}
       </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

React does not give access to content outside of src directory to be used in React code.

Possible solutions may be:

- Move your svg inside src directory (Recommended).
- Use Public folder and access it like this.
  ([Using Public Folder](https:////facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder))

.

```
// Using Public Folder
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const svgs = ["0.svg", "23.svg",...];
    return(
       <div>
         {svgs.map(svg => 
            <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/svgfolder/${svg}`} alt="test"></img>
         }
       </div>
     )
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: but how can we loop it as i have some x number of svg files ?

Comment: Where you have to display multiple images?

Comment: say in table kind off thing i have 50 svg 's

Comment: Do you need to display all these 50 images on one screen?

Comment: If you have an array of svg names that are present in svg folder then you use array methods like .map here. To display all these images.

Comment: but how will u render those file name either from src folder or public folder i tried to retrieve import svgs from "../public/svgfolder/ or import svgs from "../src/svgfolder/ but unable to retreive

Comment: we have to mention file names in con but why what if we have 100 file then we need to give 100 name in const  ?

Comment: You want import all files from directory. This can only be implemented using third party npm plugin like **https://github.com/diegohaz/list-react-files**.

Comment: like an array can't we read ? assume if u have some 150files in public folder then u have to give 150 file name in const right

Comment: Use npm plugin to get file names available in svg folder. Then use this array to display images.

Comment: what abt setting up a json file and giving names in that and then consume that file by using map we can display right

Comment: Yes this can be done. But still the same you need to manage JSON file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading SVGs how you are currently doing it, I would recommend inline SVG as React Components. This way you can control the styling with props and state too as well as many other useful capabilities.

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const GithubSVG = (props) => {
  const { backFill, className, mainFill } = props.props;
  return(
    <svg
      className={className}
      height='512'
      id='Layer_1'
      version='1.1'
      viewBox='0 0 512 512'
      width='512'
    >
      <defs id='defs'/>
      <g id='g'>
        <rect
          height='512'
          id='rect'
          style={{
            fill: backFill,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fillRule: 'nonzero',
            stroke: 'none'
          }}
          width='512'
          x='0'
          y='0'
        />
        <path
          d='a bunch of random numbers'
          id='svg'
          style={{fill: mainFill}}
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  )
}

export default GithubSVG;
```

You can now import that component anywhere.

Comment: ok how can i import some n number of svg's from public folder and consume it  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Webpack, it is better to use `svg-url-loader` for webpack & package them with your deployments.

Add below in your webpack.config

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.svg/,
        use: { loader: 'svg-url-loader', options: {} },
      }
   ]
}
```

app.css

```
.zero {
  background: url('../public/svgfolder/0.svg') no-repeat;
}
```

app.js

```
<i className="zero" />
```

Comment: its not about a single svg . here i have some n number of svgs i  have to map it and display ?

Comment: Did you even try it yet? It's literally called SVG loader. What do you think it does.

Comment: @cullanrocks for single file it is ok but how to get access for  some n number of files